# Radial progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

I'm working on creating a radial progress bar, I'm getting the percent from the database.

So what should happen:

1- Getting the percent value from the database (Done)

2- Send the value from script to div in HTML.

3- jQuery takes the percent div and create the radial progress.

But I'm getting a problem in number 2, I'm not sending the value correctly because it is in div inside a div.

This is the div part:

```
 <div class="ia-radial red1">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle r="25" cx="50" cy="50" id="pie" />
    </svg>
    <div id="precent"></div>
  </div>
```

This is the part where I send a value I'm getting from my script method that gets the percent from database:

```
document.getElementById('ia-radial red1').getElementById('precent').innerHTML = HappyCity;
```

And this is the jQuery part:

```
     $('.ia-radial').each(function(){
     var utilslider = parseInt($(this).find("#precent").html()),
      circle = $(this).find("#pie"),
      radius = parseInt(circle.attr('r')),
      circumf= 2 * radius * Math.PI,
      percentV = (utilslider / 100) * circumf;

  circle.css('strokeDasharray', percentV + " " + circumf);
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/MoorLex/pen/XdwwKr?depth=everything&order=popularity&page=5&q=radial%20progress&show_forks=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things may help you fix the issue.

First, the method `document.getElementById()` returns a DOM element that doesn't have a method `getElementById`, meaning that it cannot get called twice in a row like that. Also, `ia-radial red1` are two class names, rather than ID names, so `getElementById` won't succeed in selecting `<div class="ia-radial red1">`. The best way to get around this, is to use one ID name per div in the document, which is the conventional way. Try setting `<div id="precent">` to `<div class="precent">` (and also don't forget to change `#precent` to `.precent` in the CSS file). Then assign a specific ID to both divs (e.g. `id="precent1`" and `id="precent2"`). Then you can select a div with `document.getElementById('precent1').innerHTML = HappyCity;`.

Second, the jQuery part gets called only once, when the page loads. You need to call it again after `innerHTML` is changed. Try wrapping it in a function like so, and adding an input `idName` so you can call the function on a particular element:

```
function updateProgressBar(idName) {
  $('.ia-radial').each(function(){
  var utilslider = parseInt($(this).find("#"+idName).html()), // Note the idName
    circle = $(this).find("#pie"),
    radius = parseInt(circle.attr('r')),
    circumf= 2 * radius * Math.PI,
    percentV = (utilslider / 100) * circumf;

    circle.css('strokeDasharray', percentV + " " + circumf);
  });
}
```

Now, putting the two things together, you can update each element like so:

```
updateProgressBar("precent1");

document.getElementById('precent1').innerHTML = HappyCity;

// Update progress bar after changing innerHTML
updateProgressBar("precent1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something similar to this with jQuery...

```
   $('.ia-radial.red1').children('#precent').html(HappyCity)
```